# Is it possible to use HD6450 and HD4350 on the same computer?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I'm looking to put 2 cards HD6450 and HD4350 on my computer so that I have 2 HDMI outputs. Will they be able to work together?

I'am wondering about this since on AMD's driver site, HD4xxx series use a different driver than HD6xxx series, and I wonder what would happen if I try to install both of them at the same time?

Comment: They should. What happens when you put them both in?

Comment: @DarthAndroid - They use different drivers. HD4350 is not supported by recent releases of `Catalyst Software Suite`.  The user will unlikely be able to install 2 different graphic drivers as they will conflict because they are the same driver just different revisions.

Comment: Care to link to your specific AMD 6450? If it has DVI/DisplayPort then you could just buy an adapter that converts it to HDMI if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: it has DVI, but I need HDMI for the sound. I haven't got my hand on the 4350 yet, I've just found one dirt cheap and wonder if I should get it